# ¿Cómo copiar la salida de dput() al portapapeles?

Tags: r

La función `dput()` es muy útil para compartir datos entre colegas o incluso en esta comunidad:

```
dput(head(mtcars, 2))

structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6), disp = c(160, 
160), hp = c(110, 110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9), wt = c(2.62, 2.875
), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02), vs = c(0, 0), am = c(1, 1), gear = c(4, 
4), carb = c(4, 4)), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"
), class = "data.frame")
```

La salida la copiamos en un mail o en una pregunta y luego quien la reciba solo deberá ejecutar ese código directamente en el interprete de R y tendrá 20 filas de ejemplo del objeto original. Sin embargo tiene un problema, con objetos relativamente grandes, la salida suele ser compleja y podemos equivocarnos al copiarla, haciendo luego inusable el código. Me gustaría copiar la salida directamente al portapapeles de forma directa, he probado `writeClipboard()` pero lamentablemente espera un vector de caracteres y `dput()` entrega un `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Un forma posible es trabajar con `deparse()` que retorna lo mismo de `dput()` pero en la forma de un vector de caracteres:

```
toclp <- function(x, lng = NA) {
  # Forzamos evaluación del objeto sino tenemos problemas con 
  # vectores, listas y objetos simples
  force(x) 
  if (is.na(lng)) {
    out <- deparse(x)
  } else {
    out <- deparse(head(x, lng))
  }
  writeClipboard(out)
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
toclp(mtcars, 2)
```

Luego al pegar:

```
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6), disp = c(160, 
                                                        160), hp = c(110, 110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9), wt = c(2.62, 2.875
                                                        ), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02), vs = c(0, 0), am = c(1, 1), gear = c(4, 
                                                                                                                        4), carb = c(4, 4)), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"
                                                                                                                        ), class = "data.frame")
```

Nota:

- No todos los objetos puedes ser deconstruidos de esta forma, pero si con los más habituales como listas, vectores y data.frames.