# Por qué un numero largo cambia sus valores después de convertirlo de string a numeric?

Tags: r, string, formato

Concatene algunas variables para crear un ID, cree dos tipos de variables concatenadas (ambas con los mismos valores), una en formato string y la otra en formato numeric. Pero los resultados difieren en los ultimos 2 digitos, se supone que deberian ser los mismos, use los mismos valores.

```
id_viv <- SD %>%          
  mutate(id_viv = 
     as.numeric(paste0(cd_a, ent, con, v_sel,
                                    n_hog, h_mud, n_ren, n_pro_viv)),
     id_viv_char = (paste0(cd_a, ent, con, v_sel,
                         n_hog, h_mud, n_ren, n_pro_viv)))
```

[image]

Primero pensé que los valores eran iguales y solo se veian diferente, pero al aplicar la funcion de duplicated me di cuenta de que si cambian los valores en realidad

Primer resultado

```
table(duplicated(id_viv$id_viv))
```

output:

```
FALSE   TRUE 
403296    356
```

Segundo resultado

```
table(duplicated(id_viv$id_viv_char))
```

output:

```
 FALSE   TRUE 
 403644      8
```

Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?

P.D: Esto también pasa en STATA

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando una muestra de tus datos originales (SD). Puedes revisar esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/580019/61530) donde se explica una manera muy útil para compartir datos de R en este sito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que con número grandes, al menos los que superan la capacidad de un entero: `.Machine$integer.max`, R terminará usando un `double` para representarlo, y aquí entras en el mundo  (y sus problemas) de los números de punto flotante, que de manera muy básica significa que vas a tener problemas de precisión:

```
numero <- '86326003012103109'
numero == as.character(as.numeric(numero))
[1] FALSE

numero <- '86326003012103104'
numero == as.character(as.numeric(numero))
[1] TRUE
```

En este ejemplo vemos que el `86326003012103109` no puede representarse exactamente como un número de punto flotante y sin embargo `86326003012103104` si.

No sé específicamente para que quieres trabajar estos números grandes como numéricos, si no vas a hacer cálculos con ellos te diría que los manejes como cadenas directamente, sino vas a tener que recurrir a algún paquete que maneje números grandes con precisión, por ejemplo `gmp`.

```
library(gmp)
numero <- '86326003012103109'
numero == as.character(as.bigq(numero))
[1] TRUE
```

Con respecto a tu último comentario:

> Esto también pasa en STATA

Claro, por que no es un problema del lenguaje, es un problema intrínseco del formato de punto flotante, cualquier lenguaje o sistema que use este tipo de dato tendrá los mismos inconvenientes, y todo deriva de la imposibilidad de representar un número real en un espacio de memoria limitado.