# Eliminar filas bajo ciertas condiciones RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

cómo están?
tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una base con muchas filas, de las cuales, debo eliminar todas aquellas que
cumplen con 3 condiciones simultáneamente. Por ejemplo:

| N | sol | con | dia | NCar | NIns | isom | area rep | tipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | con | 0.001 | 1 | 160s | 0 | s | 6.083543e-01 | 1 |
| 2 | con | 0.001 | 1 | 161c | 1 | c | 1.391274e-03 | 1 |
| 3 | con | 0.001 | 1 | 161c | 1 | c | 2.812804e-03 | 1 |
| 4 | con | 0.001 | 1 | 180s | 0 | s | 3.791027e-01 | 1 |
| 619 | lim | 0.003 | 2 | 160s | 0 | s | 5.723237e-01 | 1 |
| 620 | lim | 0.003 | 2 | 161t | 1 | l | 1.096077e-02 | 1 |
| 621 | lim | 0.003 | 2 | 161c | 1 | l | 3.896926e-03 | 1 |
| 630 | lim | 0.003 | 2 | 190s | 0 | s | 1.340253e-02 | 1 |
| 631 | lim | 0.003 | 2 | 190s | 0 | l | 9.274320e-03 | 1 |
| 632 | lim | 0.003 | 3 | 160s | 0 | s | 6.527778e-01 | 1 |
| 633 | lim | 0.003 | 3 | 180s | 0 | s | 3.211201e-01 | 1 |
| 634 | lim | 0.003 | 3 | 181c | 1 | c | 2.610209e-02 | 1 |
| 635 | lim | 0.003 | 4 | 160s | 0 | s | 6.080091e-01 | 1 |
| 636 | lim | 0.003 | 4 | 161c | 1 | c | 1.739469e-03 | 1 |
| 642 | lim | 0.003 | 5 | 160s | 0 | s | 6.085502e-01 | 1 |
| 609 | dol | 1.573 | 5 | 182i | 2 | i | 1.479901e-03 | 2 |
| 610 | dol | 1.573 | 5 | 182i | 2 | i | 2.343052e-03 | 2 |
| 611 | dol | 1.573 | 5 | 182i | 2 | i | 3.179129e-03 | 2 |
| 612 | dol | 1.573 | 4 | 160s | 0 | s | 6.663188e-01 | 3 |
| 613 | dol | 1.573 | 4 | 161c | 1 | c | 9.283267e-04 | 3 |
| 614 | dol | 1.573 | 4 | 161c | 1 | c | 1.239676e-03 | 3 |

Necesito eliminar todas las filas que sean así: SOL = LIM  & DIA= 2 & ISOM = l

Intenté hacer esto:

```
base2 <- base1[base1$sol!= "lim" & base1$dia!= "2", base1$isom != "l"]
```

Pero no me funcionó, porque elimina todas las filas que cumplan al menos uno de los criterios definidos y yo necesito eliminar los casos que tengan las 3 condiciones AL MISMO TIEMPO.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Prueba a escribir un "doble igual" en lugar de sólo uno; es decir, `base2 <- base1[,base1$sol!== "lim" & base1$dia!== "2" base1$isom != ="l"]`. Además, fíjate que he cambiado la coma que has puesto, para selecionar las filas, pon la coma después del primer corchete.

Comment: No se puede poner un "doble igual", pues R dice que es un error

Comment: Si lo que quieres es obtener un valor lógico (TRUE o FALSE) necesariamente tienes que poner el doble igual para realizar la comprobación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me suena a que es un problema de las leyes de Morgan de lógica `~A&~B == ~(AvB)`. En todo caso, para lograr quitar solo las filas donde las tres columnas sean distintas podemos probar la condición de igualdad de las 3 columnas y después negar esta condición. Aqui un ejemplo con el conjunto `npk` precargado en R.

```
#Elimina las filas donde almenos una columna no es igual
npk[npk$block!=1&npk$N!=1&npk$P!=1,]

#Elimina las filas donde todas las columnas son son distintas 
npk[!(npk$block==1&npk$N==1&npk$P==1),]
```

Para el código que muestras de ejemplo la solución seria:

```
base2 <- base1[!(base1$sol== "lim" & base1$dia== "2"$base1$isom == "l"),]
```

Notas:

1. En el código que compartes la "," después de `base1$dia!= "2"` creo que debería ser  `&` y la coma de dimisión de base 1 seria después de `base1$isom != "l"`;
2. Si bien es totalmente válida, podría compartir sus datos en un formato mas amigable para que los demás podemos leerlos y evitar el uso de imágenes para este propósito. Para compartir datos de R puedes seguir los consejos dados en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/580019/61530)
   y sería bueno que realices el [tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.